# How to install a last but one version of a package?

Tags: apt, package-management

I use Ubuntu 18.04.4
If I want to install a specific version of a Ubuntu package, I try the next command:
For example:

```
sudo apt-get install thunderbird=1:68.7.0+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
E: Version '1:68.7.0+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1' for 'thunderbird' was not found
```

Where is apt-get looking for the package 'thunderbird' with version 18.04.1?

Must I download this package before the `apt-get install` command?
If yes, in in which directory should the package be placed?
If no, how can I install the last but one version?

Comment: What do you mean by last but one? if you run `sudo apt install thunderbird` you get the last version installed on your machine. Use `apt policy thunderbird` to see what versions are available to you for install.

Comment: Suppose Thunderbird version 18.04.1 is installed and works correct.
Then I run 'sudo apt upgrade' and Thurderbird is upgraded to version 18.04.2.
Suppose I discover a problem in Thunderbird version 18.04.2
Then I want to go back to Thunderbird version 18.04.1
How can I install Thunderbird version 18.04.1 again?

Answer (score 0):

The **specific** version of a package is provided by repository. The official repository indexes are located at https://packages.ubuntu.com . Also this list may be obtained by using `apt-cache policy thunderbird` on the local machine.

The current status of repositories for Thunderbird [is available by using search on the same site](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=thunderbird).
For 18.04 LTS you now get:

> bionic (18.04LTS) (mail): Email, RSS and newsgroup client with integrated spam filter
>   1:68.8.0+build2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [**security**]: amd64 i386
>   1:52.7.0+build1-0ubuntu1 [**ports**]: arm64 armhf ppc64el
>   bionic-updates (mail): Email, RSS and newsgroup client with integrated spam filter
>   1:68.8.0+build2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x

As you can see there is no 68.7 here. Also there is no such package version on [the mirror](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunderbird/).

If you really know what and why you are trying to achieve - download package manually and install it [from LaunchPad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/1:68.7.0+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1).

**Also please note that downloading old package version may have security issues.**